# Unable to Send Requests with Unrecognized Statuses in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, postman

I am working on a Spring Boot application where I have a controller method designed to handle requests with various enrolment statuses. However, I've encountered an issue where requests with specific statuses, such as "DENIED" are not reaching the controller method as expected.
Requests with unrecognized statuses are resulting in a "Bad Request" response, and the controller method is not being invoked.

```
@PatchMapping("/{enrollmentId}")
public EnrollmentResponseDto updateEnrollmentStatus(
        @PathVariable final UUID enrollmentId,
        @RequestBody final ApproveEnrollmentDto dto,
        @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") final String jwtToken){
    // Method implementation
}
```

DTO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ApproveEnrollmentDto {
    private EnrollmentStatus status;
}
```

I have an `EnrollmentStatus` enum with validation logic to ensure valid transitions between statuses.

```
public enum EnrollmentStatus {
    PENDING, APPROVED, DENIED, ACTIVE, COMPLETED, CANCELED;
}
```

Example of a request payload causing the issue:

```
{
    "status": "DENIEDD"
}
```

I have attempted to debug the issue by logging the request processing flow, but I cannot identify why requests with unrecognized statuses are not reaching the controller method.
I expect the controller method to be invoked for all valid requests, and the system should gracefully handle requests with unrecognized statuses.

Comment: You have an enum `EnrollmentStatus` which restrict the status you can have and you pass `DENIEED` which is not inside the domain of the enum: the response is not valid. Either use a String, either use your custom mapper (if you use Jackson, `JsonDeserialize`) or if you mapper support it, try with a setter of String doing the conversion.